# MongooseJS - Retrieve all documents based on ObjectIds in an array

Tags: mongoose

I am using MongooseJs with Express / Node.

I have a Schema like this:

```
ParentSchema = {  
    _id: ObjectID,
    children = [ObjectId]
}
```

I have another Schema like this:

```
ChildSchema = {  
    _id: ObejctID,
    name: String
    age: Number
}
```

The _id in `ChildSchema` is basically stored in the children array of `ParentSchema`.
Now, my question is how to get the documents in the model of the ChildSchema when I have only their ObjectIds in the children. Basically, if children = [1, 2, 3, 4[, how do I fetch ALL the records from ChildSchema with _id in [1, 2, 3, 4]?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is [**populate**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Example:

```
ParentSchema = {  
    _id: ObjectID,
    children = [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "ChildModelName"}]
} 

ParentModel.find().populate("children").exec(cb);
```